# Why my textfield loses its value when I hit submit or the right icon?

Tags: flutter, textfield

I have a problem with the textfield that when I hit submit it loses the value,
My code:

```
Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 20),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 6),
      width: size.width * 0.85,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xFFF1E6FF),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(29),
                  ),
        child: TextField(
             controller: emailController,
             cursorColor: Color(0xFF6F35A5),
             decoration: InputDecoration(
             icon: Icon(
                 Icons.person,
                 color: Color(0xFF6F35A5),
                      ),
                 hintText: 'Email',
                 border: InputBorder.none,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have defined your `TextEditingController();` inside the class.

Try defining it outside of all the classes, it worked for me when I was facing this issue I don't know what is the technicality behind this.

Comment: Yeah it worked for me too but I don't quite understand what happened

Comment: @OKKO yup same here, i was playing with it and somehow got this solution i don't exactly know why it works this way :)